# Upload new app on playstore - import failed

Tags: android, upload, google-play

I am trying to upload my new app on the playstore. 
I have a .apk file and .jks file
when I try upload it, it just says :

> Failed to import.
>
> You have imported an APK that is not signed with the import
>   certificate.
>
> You must use the same certificate. The import certificate bears the
>   following fingerprint:
>
> [SHA1: 11: CA: FC: .... B1: 40: 67: 31] .
>
> The certificate used to sign the APK that you imported contains the
>   following thumbprint: [SHA1: 8E: 9D: A1:.... 1A: 63: 71: 21: 90: 3A:
>   89]

I have even renamed my package name, created new key + app but still it gives the same issue, does anyone has an idea?

Answer (score 0):

Android apps are signed by a unique certificate generated by the developer. The authenticity of the app that it came from the same developer is ensured by using the same certificate to deliver future versions and apps.
From the given error, you have used a different certificate to sign the app.
**Instead of generating a new certificate (key), use the previous one.**
You can also [Google Play for Dynamic Delivery](https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle/#dynamic_delivery).

You will find more detailed information and options about app signing 
[HERE](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing).